# find unique times among years in time series

Tags: matlab, vector

Suppose I have a date vector shown here by tt and a corresponding data series corresponding to aa. For example:

```
dd = datestr(datenum('2007-01-01 00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'):1/24:...
     datenum('2011-12-31 23:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'),...
     'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM');
tt = datevec(datenum(dd,'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'));
tt(1002,:) = [];
aa = rand(length(tt),1)
```

How is it possible to ensure that the hours and days are consistent among the years?

For example, I only want to keep times that are the same among years e.g.

```
2009-01-01 01:00
```

would be the same as

```
2010-01-01 01:00
```

ad so on.

If one year has a measurements at

```
2009-01-01 02:00
```

but yyyy-01-01 02:00

is not present in the other years, this time should re removed.

I would like the to return tt and aa where only those times that are consistent among the years are kept. how can this be done?

I was considering finding the indices for the unique years first as:

```
[~,~,iyears] = unique(tt(:,1),'rows');
```

and then find the indices for the unique month, day, and hour as:

```
[~,~,iid] = unique(tt(:,2:4),'rows');
```

but I am not sure how to combine these to give the desired output?

Comment: What do you mean by "consistent"? Do you want to check that you datevector is in order, and that there are no points missing?

Comment: By consistent I mean have the same mm-dd HH:MM among years. I've changed the OP to demonstrate this.

Comment: @Kate Curious if any of the answers provided here worked for you.

Comment: For my dataset, they did not. I am still trying to find why they do not.

Answer (score 0):

The solution below uses a loop to store data in an unitialized array, which can be inefficient, but unless your dataset is huge (with many, many years) it should do the job. The general idea is to break the dataset up into years. I am storing the resulting time-vectors in a cell array, because they probably won't have the same length. I then do a set-intersection of all the time vectors, to get a vector of common times. From there it's straight forward.

```
years = unique(tt(:,1), 'rows');

% Put the "sub-times" of each year into cell array
for ii = 1:length(years)
    times_each_year{ii} = tt(tt(:,1)==years(ii),2:end);
end

% Do intersection of all "sub-times" sets
common_times = times_each_year{1};
for ii = 2:length(years)
    common_times = intersect(common_times, times_each_year{ii},'rows');
end

% Find and delete the points that are not member of the "sub-times":
idx = ~ismember(tt(:,2:end),common_times,'rows');
deleted_points = datestr(tt(idx,:)); % for later review
tt(idx,:) = [];
```

However, note that the `deleted_points` vector contains more points than one might expect. That's because 2008 was a leap year, and all the points corresponding to Febr. 29th were deleted.

Another such oddity might await you if your data is "contaminated" by daylight savings time.

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
a1 = str2num(datestr(tt,'mmddHHMM')); %// If in your data minutes are always 00, you can use 'mmddHH' instead and save some runtime
k1 = unique(a1);
gt1 = histc(a1,k1);
valid_rows = ismember(a1,k1(gt1==max(gt1)));
new_tt = tt(valid_rows,:); %// Desired tt output
new_aa = aa(valid_rows,:); %// Desired aa output
```

**Explanation**

To understand how it works, let's test out the code at a micro-level. Let's assume some small data that corresponds to `tt` -

```
data1 = [4 5 1 4 5 1 4 5 6]
```

`data1` is the data collected over few sets and resembles `tt` that has data over few years with month, date, hour and minutes when these four parameters are conglomerated into a single parameter.

One can notice it would represent data from three sets/years with data as `{4,5}`, `{1,4,5}` and `{1,4,5,6}`. Our job is to found out all those values in `data1` that is repeated across all the three years/sets of data. Thus, the final output must be `{4,5}`.

Let's see how this can be coded up.

**Step 1:** Get the unique values

```
unique_val = unique(data1)
```

We would have - `[1 4 5 6]`

**Step 2:** Get the count of unique values in the data

```
count_unique_val = histc(data1,unique_val)
```

Output is - `[2 3 3 1]`

**Step 3:** Get the indices from the unique values array where their counts are equal to the maximum of counts, indicating those are the unique values that are repeated across all the sets.

```
index1 = count_unique_val==max(count_unique_val)
```

Output comes out as - `[0 1 1 0]`

**Step 4:** Get those "consistent" unique values

```
consistent_val = unique_val(index1)
```

Gives us - `[4 5]`, which is what we were looking for.

**Step 5:** Finally get the indices where the consistent data is present, 
which can be used later on to select the rows with "consistent" data.

```
index_consistent_val = ismember(data1,consistent_val)
```

Output is - `[1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0]`, which makes sense too.

Please note that in the original code `a1 = str2num(datestr(tt,'mmddHHMM'));` gets us the single parameter from the four parameters of month, date, hour and minutes as discussed in the comments earlier too.